# How can I find the position of the outputs from pandas.Series.str.extractall()?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

For example, suppose I had the following `pd.Series`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(['ASDFQWEFASDF', 'QEGGRGQFSAFAD'])
>>> series
0    ASDFQWEFASDF
1    QEGGRGQFSAFAD
```

and I wanted to find everything matching the regex `(.A)`. I can find the text matches themselves with `series.str.extractall()`, but not where they occur:

```
>>> series.str.extractall('(.A)')
          0
  match    
0 0      FA
1 0      SA
  1      FA
```

How can I get the location of these matches, e.g. in another column, like this:

```
               0
  match index   
0 0     7     FA
1 0     8     SA
  1     10    FA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas cannot return the index/span because it uses [`findall` under the hood](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/strings.py#L2971-L2974) (`findall` returns strings and not `re.Match`-objects). As an alternative you could try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

series = pd.Series(['ASDFQWEFASDF', 'QEGGRGQFSAFAD'])
regexp = re.compile(r"(.A)")
matches = series.apply(lambda r: list(regexp.finditer(r)))
matches.explode().apply(lambda r: pd.Series({"start": r.span()[0],
                                             "end": r.span()[1],
                                             "match": r.group(0)}))
```

Result:

```
    start   end match
0   7   9   FA
1   8   10  SA
1   10  12  FA
```

Comment: This is some god tier Pandas/regex. Thank you so much!